# how do i stop the pre-condition from failing in the below example in ADA Spark

Tags: ada, formal-methods, spark-ada

For a project I am currently trying to write a mini pilot assistance system for an imaginary aircraft. The task is to learn Ada Spark, not avionics. I have modelled the plane components I wish to use, done some tests in the main file to check the components work as expected, and all is fine, and now I am to add pre and post conditions to functions to make sure my plane is super safe. One such safety measure is to make sure the engine cannot be switched on whilst the plane is in tow, or vice versa, switch to tow whilst the engine is on.

I have modelled an engine as a highly complex record, with one attribute, type OnOff, which takes one of the values On, or Off.  Note I plan on expanding upon the attributes, so it isn't going to remain a one attribute record.

Here is the engines specification file

```
package engines with SPARK_Mode
is

type OnOff is (On, Off);
type Engine is record
  isOn: OnOff;
end record;


procedure switchOn (x : in out Engine);
procedure switchOff (x : in out Engine);

end engines;
```

My plane is put together like so:

```
   type Plane is record
     engine1: Engine;
     engine2: Engine;
     gearOfLanding: LandingGear;
     doorPax1, doorPax2, doorServ1, doorServ2, 
     doorCockpit: Door;
     panelOfReadings: ReadingsPanel;
     panelOfAlerts: AlertsPanel;
     planOfFlight: FlightPlan;
     speedLimits: SpeedLimit;
     altitudeLimits: AltitudeLimit;
     attitudeLimits: AttitudeLimit; 
     litresPerMile: Integer;
     fuelTank1: FuelTank;
  end record;
```

The procedure switchOnEngine within the planes file takes an engine as an input and calls switchOn from the engines file. Here is the specification and below, the body:

```
  procedure switchOnEngine (x : in out Engine; y : in Plane) with
    Pre => y.panelOfReadings.mode /= Tow,
    Post => x = (isOn => On) and y.panelOfReadings.mode /= Tow;



  procedure switchOnEngine (x : in out Engine; y : in Plane)
  is
  begin
      switchOn(x);
  
  end switchOnEngine;
```

The plane is passed in as a variable so I can check various attributes for my pre and post conditions, but I am getting warning messages I am unsure how to resolve.

```
precondition might fail
cannot prove y.panelOfReadings.mode /= Tow e.g when .......mode =>Tow
```

The following line is also giving an error from the main file where I control my plane

```
switchOnEngine(AirForceOne.engine1, AirForceOne);

formal parameters x and y are aliased, and this is being marked as a 'high' priority warning.
```

here is the initialisation of the plane in the main file

```
AirForceOne : Plane := (
   engine1 => (isOn => Off),
   engine2 => (isOn => Off),
   litresPerMile => 5,
   gearOfLanding => (isExtended => Extended),
   doorPax1 => (isClosed => Closed, isLocked => Unlocked),
   doorPax2 => (isClosed => Closed, isLocked => Unlocked),
   doorServ1 => (isClosed => Closed, isLocked => Unlocked),
   doorServ2  => (isClosed => Closed, isLocked => Unlocked),
   doorCockpit => (isClosed => Closed, isLocked => Unlocked),
   fuelTank1 => (capacity=>26000, currentFuel=>26000),
   planOfFlight => (distFromDest => 1500),
   panelOfReadings =>
       (mode => Tow,
        currentSpeed => 0,
        altitud => 0,
        attitud =>
            (currentPitch=>0,
             currentRoll =>0)
       ),
   panelOfAlerts =>
       (approachingStallSpeed => Off,
        unRestrictedSpeed => Off,
        withinLandingSpdRange => Off,
        withinOptCruiseAlt => Off,
        withinOptCruiseSpeed => Off,
        takeoffSpeedReached => Off,
        fuelStatus => Off,
        maxPitchAngleExceeded => Off,
        maxRollAngleExceeded => Off),
   speedLimits =>
       (minLanding => 180,
        maxLanding => 200,
        minStall => 110,
        minTakeoff => 130,
        maxRestricted => 300,
        maxGroundMode => 10),
   altitudeLimits =>
       (minFlight => 500,
        maxFlight => 41000,
        optCruiseAlt => 36000,
        maxRestrictedSpeed => 10000,
        maxInitiateFlareMode => 100),
   attitudeLimits =>
       (maxRoll => 30,
        maxPitch => 30,
        minRoll => -30,
        minPitch => -30)
 );
```

Any help would be great. I thought it would be enough to suggest in the pre condition that the plane cannot be in tow, but it seems to not be enough.

Comment: The procedure switchengineon takes two independent parameters, a plane and an engine. There is no logical connection between the plane and one of its two engines. Therefore there is no logical connection between the plane being towed and the state of the engine.

Comment: "ADA Spark": Ada is not an acronym; SPARK is

Comment: Choosing good names is important for writing correct S/W. X is not a good name for an engine, nor Y for a plane.

Comment: What should happen if X is not an engine of Y? How can you tell?

Comment: Lots of useful answers here thanks a lot guys I see where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `Switchonengine` is to change the state of the plane. Writing it to change the state of an engine is going to complicate things.

```
Max_Engines : constant := 100; -- The Lillium jet has 36, so I hope this is enough

type Engine_Num is range 1 .. Max_Engines;

type Engine_Info is ...

type Engine_Map is array (Engine_Num range <>) of Engine_Info with
   Dynamic_Predicate => Engine_Map'First = 1;

type Plane_Info (Num_Engines : Engine_Num) is record
   Engine : Engine_Map (1 .. Num_Engines);
   ...

procedure Turn_On (Engine : in Engine_Num; Plane : in out Plane_Info) with
   Pre => Engine in 1 .. Plane.Num_Engines and then
          (not Running (Plane.Engine (Engine) ) and not Under_Tow (Plane),
   Post => Running (Plane.Engine (Engine) );

Air_Force_One : Plane_Info (Num_Engines => 4);
```

Comment: I've just returned to my planes work and would like to thank you again. I basically removed my Plane record, and made all the attributes global values, totally simplifying it. Trying to apply good OOP practices was making it far too complicated given my experience with Ada, and your answers really cleared up where I was going wrong.